# Google Sheets Pivot Table, Summary by Day

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I have a sheet with 2500 dates & times of when customers have placed their order.

I want to do a heatmap or a bar graph to show which days of the week are the busiest.
I rounded the exact times using `mround` to round up or down to the nearest whole hour.

But when I pivot on the data, for example, The 'Sunday 10:00 AM' at the beginning of the column I guess is not the same as the 'Sunday 10:00 AM' for the following week, and so on.

I tried converting the date to_text.  Which worked, but then the pivot table couldn't be sorted in chronological order.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here's a link to the copy of the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_B4DlZoD36q8cAYRw6spSiDlSkUS1FTfIpvV0w2otCQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you want that heatmap/chart to represent one week interval to see the "heat" per weekdays, right?

Comment: also, is Sunday for you the 1st day of the week or 7th?

Comment: yeah so basically I want the total number of transactions for all the Sunday 10:00 AM summed up into one entry.  Which, if I filter the column it works correctly (looks like there are 80 entries for this time). But the pivot table does not work.

Comment: Yes Sunday is day 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of your formula in **B** column and the whole pivot table, use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 {WEEKDAY(A2:A), TEXT(A2:A, "dddd am/pm hh:00 am/pm")}, ), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2),Col1 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2,Col1 
  order by Col1
  label count(Col2)''", 0)&"AM ", "PM |AM ", "")), 999^99, 2)
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: That works great.  and I don't mean to get picky.  Is there a way to then sort it so the dates are chronological?

Comment: you mean AM/PM to be in chrono order?

Comment: yeah so when I graph it, everything is in order. Sunday 10am, 11am, 12pm,... Monday 8am, 9pm, etc

Comment: yeah that would work. for sure

Comment: @MattWiner answer updated